# StateListDrawable containing Drawables with different bounds

Tags: java, android, drawable, state

Suppose I have a StateListDrawable. I want to add 2 drawables inside it: the first if it is clicked, second for any other state.

I tried it as following (pseudo-code):

```
Drawable clickdDrawable = getResourses.getDrawable(R.drawable.presseddrawable);
clickDrawable.setBounds(-100, -100, 100, 100);

Drawable otherStateDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somedrawable);
otherStateDrawable.setBounds(-50,-50, 50, 50);

StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
sld.addState(new int[]{andriod.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_focussed}, clickDrawable);
sld.addState(StateSet.WILDCARD, otherStateDrawable);
sld.setBounds(-50, -50, 50, 50);
```

now if I'm in state pressed I will get the presseddrawable, but it sticks to the bounds of StateListDrawable. So my question is: How to store Drawables with different bounds inside a StateListDrawable? Is this possible?

Comment: could you post a screenshot of what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create "custom" `Drawable`s, but before you go that way, let me invite you (and whoever is involved, often a designer) to re-think a bit what you are doing, some years ago I did a heavy work on programmatically drawn `extends Drawable`s (yet it was awesome) just to trash it few months later in favor of simplicity and practicality, I don't see why you can't achieve something like this with a well made 9-patch (a.k.a. n-patch) rather than hardcode dimensions, anyways before you call me grandpa here is a quick answer that could work for ya:

In example say you are using color drawables:

```java
public class FixedBoundsColorDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
  private boolean mFixedBoundsSet = false; // default

  public FixedBoundsColorDrawable(int color) {
    super(color);
  }

  @Override
  public void setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (!mFixedBoundsSet) {
      mFixedBoundsSet = true;
      super.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
    }
  }
}
```

With red as pressed and blue as wildcard and your values you get on a Nexus 4:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/854Hl0K.png]

You could also create a wrapper to wrap any drawable and call its methods but I would go that way as there are some `final` methods that you certainly will need.